# Optimizing and multiprocessing a specific part of program for faster execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-multiprocessing

I am running a specific program which takes ages to complete, and then I realized I might be doing something entirely stupid. Combining this with the fact that the program does not utilize the full power of my CPU, I turn here for help in optimizing the core of the code.

I am not very comfortable with multiprocessing in Python, and so the answers all around this site are not helping that much.

The specific code I am working with is:

```py
k=10000

for i in range(2,k):
  n=i

  people=[]
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    people.append(i) #create list of people, labelled with integers

  while(len(people)>1): #the game ends when there is 0 or 1 people left
    shoot=[]

    for i in people:
      choice=i
      while(choice==i):
        choice=random.choice(people) #i-th chooses a person to kill and can't choose himself
      shoot.append(choice)

    for i in shoot:
      if(i in people):
        people.remove(i) #remove killed people
```

The problem is that the `people` array can be a huge list (k an be a huge number) and the number of operations in the worst case is of the order of k factorial which can be pretty large.

I would like to use any optimizations you might suggest and also, if possible, to know how to use multiprocessing here. I have 8 virtual cores if that's any help.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What you want is the shoot list for every i?

Comment: Right. That's the main stuff.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? More specifically the part where while choice==i

Comment: Basically there is a collection of people playing a game. Every person randomly chooses another person to kill. The choice==i while loop stops them from choosing themselves to be killed. The selected people are then removed and the game continues till 1 or no people are left.

Comment: I added some comments in the code to help with understanding it. If you have other questions, do let me know.

Comment: Can a person be shot twice?

Comment: Yes. More than one person can choose to kill the same person.

Comment: it's not often, but when Python is too slow for something and i need it to go very fast, i usually rewrite it in C++ (which is [a hell of a lot faster than Python](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/gpp-python3.html) )

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes I believe that's true (since I do a lot of coding in C), but for this problem, I did require python because of several attachments to this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be faster than this:

```
import numpy as np
import concurrent
import random

k=10
num_workers = 8

def choose_shoot(people, idx):
    shoot = random.choice(tuple(people - set([idx])))
    return shoot

def find_shoot(n):

    people = set(np.arange(1, n+1))

    while(len(people)>1):

        shoot = set([*map(lambda x: choose_shoot(people, x), people)])
        people = set([*filter(lambda x: x not in shoot, people)])

    return people, len(people)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as pool:
        survivors, sizes = zip(*list(pool.map(find_shoot, range(2, k+1))))
```

The sizes is the size of each set of survivors if you want the number of singletons:

```
num_singletons = sizes.count(1)
num_empty = sizes.count(0)
```

Comment: This returns a generator of the survivors in each case

Comment: There's a small error which can be fixed with import concurrent.futures 

Is this right?

Comment: Yep, sorry! Didn't see that

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for helping. Let me see what this is doing and try to understand it.

Comment: Extremely naive question. I run a loop iterating the generator using 'next' which returns a set with either 1 or no elements. These are basically the survivors, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want the shot is basically set(np.arange(1, n+1)) - survivors

Comment: The program is working perfectly. Just a small hiccup. I want to count the number of sets with no elements and same for the singletons. Do you think you can add a faster implementation of doing this to your already perfect answer? I added a small snippet to do this but it's again using too much time. Sorry for asking naive questions :(

Comment: This is something I wanted yes, but on compiling the whole program together, it seems that this is running slower than the one in the question. For example, for k=1000, on average, your program takes on average 8 secs whereas the one in the question takes about 5 secs. There's a marked difference again for k=2000, with yours 69 secs vs question's 29.5 secs. Strange... Here's the whole code of the question if you want to compare it yourself. https://pastebin.com/qVKT2YgW